# Hide divs from the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrolling timeline with images:

```
<div class="roadmap">
  <h1 class="title">Roadmap</h1>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="swiper-roadmap">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1920/500?image=15');" data-month="February">
          <div class="swiper-slide-content"><span class="timeline-year">By House ULTIMA</span>
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Live, Love and Prosper</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1920/500?image=16');" data-month="March">
          <div class="swiper-slide-content"><span class="timeline-year">By House TITAN</span>
            <h4 class="timeline-title">International Women's Day</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All divs should be hidden except the active one. But the problem is that all divs are visible on the page. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/montel3888/pen/mYyadb)

Instead of showing two images it should actually show one and then another one when i select month. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please give more details on this question. If you're looking for a CSS property, just do display: hidden; or visibility: none;.

Comment: @Drakinite you can find more details in the [pen](https://codepen.io/montel3888/pen/mYyadb)

Comment: When you're asking questions on stackoverflow, you should add enough details to the question itself, to make it easier on the people answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
.timeline {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

check this [Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRgJmX)

Answer (score 1):

You have to made some `CSS` changes. I have added two `CSS Class` at the end of your `CSS` :

```
.swiper-slide{
  display:none;
}
.swiper-slide-active{
  display:block;
}
```

Here is an updated code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeyvKz

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.roadmap`;

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to give the two div of class "swiper-slide" distinct ids, then write javascript to toggle between the two.

```
var isFebruary = (month == "February");
document.getElementById("slide1").style.display = isFebruary ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById("slide2").style.display = isFebruary ? 'none' : 'block';
```

(You may also use attribute "hidden" of HTML5 using setAttribute() and removeAttribute())

Because you have the additional attribute data-month in the div's, you can get a bit fancier by using querySelectorAll() on the class "swiper-slide" to get the list of all div's of the class, traverse the list and hide all div's except the one matching the month. The code will then work even if you add more months to the page.